# How to extract parameters in tricky strings

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I would like to extract a function's first and second parameter (if any).

For instance, from `__('param1', 'param2')`, I would like to extract `param1` and `param2`.

Here is what I find tricky:

1. There may not be a second parameter
2. The parameter quotes may be simple or double quotes
3. A double-quoted parameter may contain a single quote, and vice-versa.

Some of the potential situations where want to extract the parameters:

```
__('My test')
__('Uber test', 'dan')
__("test t'fdgfgd")
__("test t'dfgdgf","fgf', 'dgfdg")
```

Here is [what I have tried](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/5zr).

Comment: Parsing programming languages with regexes is a hopeless enterprise in most cases. Consider a proper parser (e.g. https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right it's a bit tricky, but this works (see [demo](http://regex101.com/r/vT1lM0) with all your examples):

```
(?:__\(|\G['"]\s*,\s*)(['"])\K.*?(?=(?<!\\)\1)
```

@NiettheDarkAbsol mentioned the possibility of escaped quotes, so I added a condition for tricky strings such as:

```
__('My \'test')
__("My \"test")
```

**How does this work?**

This is a bit long for a token-by-token explanation, but...

1. This part `(?:__\(|\G['"]\s*,\s*)(['"])\K` positions us inside the opening quote, abandoning what has been matched so far thanks to "Dr. `\K`eep out". Back to this later.
2. The `.*?` lazily matches characters up to...
3. The point where the lookahead `(?=(?<!\\)\1)` can assert that what follows is the same character as the opening quote (the `\1` backreference), as long as it is not preceded by an escaping backslash (the `(?<!\\)`)
4. Okay, how did part 1 work? Before the "Dr. `\K`eep out", we either match the opening `__\(` then an opening string, captured by `(['"])` to make sure that the closing string is identical (the `\1` reference later)... or...
5. asserting with `\G` that we are positioned after the previous match's last character, the `['"]\s*,\s*` matches it's closing quote, then a comma (surrounded by optional spaces), then an opening string, captured by `(['"])` to make sure that the closing string is identical (the `\1` reference later).

And that's all there is to it!

Comment: How does this handle escaped quotes?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one regex that would give you matches:

```
(?:(?:')((?:(?!(?<!\\)').)+)(?:'(?:,\s*)?))|(?:(?:")((?:(?!(?<!\\)").)+)(?:"(?:,\s*)?))
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/lM6lS0)